# My Binary Search test is only printing out 2s

Tags: c++

My code infinitely prints out "2" to the console over and over again. Does anyone know why?
I was testing out a binary search I wrote a while ago for shits and giggles, and decided to give it a pretty small "dataset". In the terminal, it just prints "2"s forever.

```
#include "libraries.cpp"
    
int main(){
    vector<int> data;
    for(int i = 0; i <= 1000; i++){
         data.insert(data.begin(), i);
    }
    
    auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();  
    cout << binSearch(data,randrange(1,1000)) << endl;
    auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

My binary search and randrange functions:

```
    int binSearch(vector<int> nums, int number){
        int min = 0;
        int max = nums.size() - 1;
        while(min != max){
            int mid = 1 + (min + max)/2;
            if(nums[mid] > number){
                max = mid;
            }else if(nums[mid] < number){
                min = mid;
            }else if(nums[mid] == number){
                return mid;
            }
            cout << mid << endl;
        }
        return -1;
    }

    int randrange(int x,int y){
        srand(time(0));
        int random = rand() % y + x;
        return random;
    }
```

Comment: The only print statement that loops is `cout << mid << endl;` which means `min != max` for all iterations with mid == 2.

Comment: `binSearch()` has two `return` statements. One returns `mid` and the other returns `-1`. You've arranged for `mid` to be at least `1`. So it is impossible to return `0`?

Answer (score 0):

1. In `binSearch`'s while loop, when `min==0` and `max==2` then `int mid = 1 + (min + max)/2;` evaluates to 2.  If `nums[mid] > number` then `max = 2` which means you made no progress and you have an infinite loop.  Below I use either `mid +- 1` to ensure progress on each iteration.
2. Binary search requires the data to be sorted but you pass in `data` reverse sorted.  Using `iota` as suggested by @PaulMcKenzie.
3. `randrange()` returns a value between `x` and `x+y-1` (both inclusive).  Changed it to `x` and `y` (both inclusive).
4. You generate 1001 numbers.  Changed that to 1000 (0 through 999).
5. Calling `binSearch` with a number in the range (you were missing 0 and 1001).
6. Comment out the code you didn't share with us so I could debug this for you.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <numeric>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;

int binSearch(vector<int> nums, int number) {
    int min = 0;
    int max = nums.size() - 1;
    while(min <= max) {
        int mid = (min + max) / 2;
        if(nums[mid] < number) {
            min = mid + 1;
        } else if(nums[mid] > number) {
            max = mid - 1;
        } else {
            return mid;
        }
    }
    return -1;
}

int randrange(int x, int y){
    srand(time(0));
    int random = rand() % (y - x + 1) + x;
    return random;
}
    
int main(){
    vector<int> data(1000);
    iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);
  
    //auto start = high_resolution_clock::now();  
    cout << binSearch(data,randrange(0,999)) << endl;
    //auto stop = high_resolution_clock::now(); 
    //cout << duration_cast<microseconds>(stop - start).count() << endl; 
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Don't I add a new number to the beginning of the array, making it sorted? It is just a for loop that adds an incrementing number.

Comment: @Aztro @AllanWind -- `vector<int> data(1000);  std::iota(data.begin(), data.end(), 0);`  That does all of the work you say you want to do with setting up `data`.  No loop necessary.

Comment: @Aztro that makes it sorted in descending order. First you insert 0, then you insert 1 at begining moving 0 to the end, then you insert 2 moving 1 and 0 and so on. To make it sorted you need to use `push_back` or insert to the end, not at begining.